# Error while trying run flutter at xcode for the first time

Tags: xcode, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I'm trying to run my flutter app for the first time in xcode in M1 mac and there are issues that i can't resolve.

Issues:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9EYvZ.png

My app works normally in androidStudio, including with the ios emulator.

I've already tried:

- flutter clean
- flutter pub get
- cd ios
- pod install || repo pod install

and i've already checked if xcode is opening with Rosetta (and it is), but it's still showing the issues.

I would like some help because I really don't know what the next steps to take.

Comment: First issue:
Run script build phase 'Run Script' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking 'Based on dependency analysis' in the script phase.

Resolution: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/112015

Comment: Second:
Run script build phase 'Thin Binary' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking 'Based on dependency analysis' in the script phase.

Resolution: ???

Comment: Third: FLTURLLauncherPlugin: "cannot open file '/Users/user237628/Desktop/flutter/bin/cache/artifacts/engine/ios/Flutter.xcframework/ios-arm64_x86_64-simulator/Flutter.framework/Headers/FlutterChannels.h': Operation not permitted.

Resolution: ???